# Saying Kaddish Yatom with Permission from Living Parents

Tags: halacha, kaddish, kibbud-av-veim-honoring

If both of my parents are living and they give me a reshut to say kaddish yatom if there is no avel, however the rav wishes that I not say it due to possible issues of marit ayin, who do I follow?

Of course, CYLOR (however I'd like sources when I discuss this with them).

Comment: Who are you saying it for?

Comment: Are you asking about in the rabbi's synagogue?

Comment: @Daniel, my father in particular is quite makpid that kaddish not be omitted l'chatchila, as it is a part of tefillah, thus, despite the fact that both of my parents are living, my father has instructed me quite specifically that I should say kaddish yatom if no abel is present and the sha"tz doesn't say it.

Comment: @DoubleAA, there are two minyanim within walking distance where I typically daven, it is the smaller of the two where the rav doesn't seem to appreciate the saying of kaddish bli avelim.

Comment: If this is the Chabad Rabbi you have mentioned in other questions, show him [this](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=32596&st=&pgnum=223&hilite=).

Answer (score 1):

[Orach Chaim 132:2](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=9729&st=&pgnum=415) Rama says that one can say Kadish Yasom after Aleinu even if he has parents, so long that his parents do not care. However I do not know of any source for saying it at other intervals besides after Aleinu.

Comment: How does this answer the question?

Comment: It gives a source for following his parents? But yeah...

Comment: @DoubleAA: This shows a source allowing one to say Kaddish Yasom in a specific circumstance even when his parents are alive. The question is asking for sources not for a ruling, if it is asking for a ruling it should be closed as this site does not replace a Rabbi.

Comment: @GershonGold So, according to this source, if your rabbi tells you not to say it even though your parents tell you you can say it, what should you do?

Comment: @DoubleAA: "however I'd like sources when I discuss this with them"